# .NET Maui - controlling sequence after permissions

Tags: c#, android, maui

I am new to Maui, so not familiar with the sequencing. How do I reference a tab after instantiation? Should it be through AppShell? I have a `Splash Page` that gets permissions:

```
public partial class SplashPage : ContentPage
{
    PermissionStatus LocationPermission;
    
    public SplashPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LocationPermission = PermissionStatus.Unknown;
    }
    
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        // Get Permissions
    }

}
```

Which is referenced in AppShell.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="CellularSignal1.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <TabBar x:Name="MyTabBar">
        <Tab x:Name="CellularInfo" Title="Cellular Info">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SplashPage}" Route="SplashPage"/>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CellularInfo}" Route="CellularInfo"/>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:BSInfo}" Route="BSInfo"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

I'm finding that all of the Shell Content is created `After` Appshell's `InitializeComponent()`, and it is not part of it. Therefore, if I put something like this in `AppShell.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace CellularSignal1;

#if ANDROID
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Do stuff after permissions is accepted from splash page
    }
}

#endif
```

I am not able to do something, since permissions is not accepted there.

What flow would allow me to reference `SplashPage, CellularInfo, and BSInfo` content together as a `Higher level` view model? I don't think I can do stuff in App() because it doesn't seem to know about `CellularInfo`:

```
using Microsoft.Maui;

namespace CellularSignal1;

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell();

        // MainPage.CellularInfo.DoStuffHere(); doesn't seem to work
    }
}
```

I apologize if this is really simple, I'm just getting tripped up by flow in general on Maui for some reason.

Comment: what happens if the user doesn't grant you permissions?  Generally you should request permissions when you need them, not before.  However if you must do it this way, you can make your `MainPage` `SplashPage`, and then after the permissions check you can reassign the `MainPage` to `AppShell`

Comment: I am going to need the permissions for every tab of my app, so that's the reason I'm doing it at the beginning. The app is essentially useless without permissions.

Comment: then you should probably try my suggestion.  And you still need to consider what happens if the user does not grant permissions, either on purpose or accidentally.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion. Along with what you mentioned, could I just get permissions in `App.cs`, eliminating the need for a Splash Page?

Comment: you have to display some sort of UI to the user while you prompt for permissions